# copy files from ftp to hdfs in parallel, distcp failed

Tags: ftp, hdfs

I am running a hdfs on Amazon EC2

Say, I have a ftp server where stores some data.

I just want to copy these data directly to hdfs in a parallel way (which maybe more efficient).

I think hadoop distcp is what I need.

But

```
$ bin/hadoop distcp ftp://username:passwd@hostname/some/path/ hdfs://namenode/some/path
```

doesn't work.

```
13/07/05 16:13:46 INFO tools.DistCp: srcPaths=[ftp://username:passwd@hostname/some/path/]
13/07/05 16:13:46 INFO tools.DistCp: destPath=hdfs://namenode/some/path
Copy failed: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input source ftp://username:passwd@hostname/some/path/ does not exist.
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.checkSrcPath(DistCp.java:641)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.copy(DistCp.java:656)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:881)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:908)
```

I checked the path by copying the ftp path in Chrome , and the file really exists, I can even download it.

And then, I tried to list the files under the path by:

```
$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls ftp://username:passwd@hostname/some/path/
```

It ends with:

```
ls: Cannot access ftp://username:passwd@hostname/some/path/: No such file or directory.
```

That seems the same pb.

Any workaround here ?

Thank you in advance.

Hao.

Answer (score 0):

ftp and hdfs are different protocols, distcp can just copy files between two different hdfs cluster, so there maybe two solutions: 1) put your ftp files to local hdfs cluster and distcp to EC2 cluster. 2) or get your file to EC2 server and put the file to EC2 cluster. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are running the hadoop nodes behind a nat. FTP fails when using Active data transfer mode. you can switch to passive mode by adding the following configuration to your `core-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>{name-node}:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.ftp.host</name>
    <value>{ftp-server-ip}</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.ftp.host.port</name>
    <value>21</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.ftp.password.{ftp-server-ip}</name>
    <value>{password}</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.ftp.user.{ftp-server-ip}</name>
    <value>{username}</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.ftp.data.connection.mode</name>
    <value>PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE</value>
</property>
```

more details on various configurations : [core-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml)

make sure to replace all values within `{}` with the actual values for your setup